# Sorting entries with value "0" as last

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to retrieve the rows in a db using hibernate criteria.
I want to get entries with value "0" for column in the end using Hibernate . For example, if the entries are appearing in the DB as follows for column:

### Column

0
2
3
1
0
Then after executing query i should get

### Column

1
2
3
0
0

Comment: show us what you tried so far and where you require help / assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a good article [here](http://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-sort) on how to inject sorting criteria into Hibernate objects.

To achieve the kind of sorting you are looking for you would use a trick like:

```
String hql = "... ORDER BY CASE WHEN f.value = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, f.value";
```

Note that this is untested code and should be used only to understand the idea. Your database may require a different form for the `CASE` keyword.

Essentially, you sort by two values, one that is hard-coded to put all zeros at the end, then sub-sort by the actual value.